# Filter, replace group values in python plot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plot, jupyter-notebook

***Original dataframe***

```
             Country  Gender  Arr-Dep  Year  Value
0            Austria    Male  IN  1974  13728
1            Austria    Male  OUT  1974  17977
2            Austria  Female  IN  1974   8541
3            Austria  Female  OUT  1974   8450
4            Austria   Total  IN  1974  22269
5            Austria   Total  OUT  1974  26427
6            Belgium    Male  IN  1974   2412
7            Belgium    Male  OUT  1974   2800
8            Belgium  Female  IN  1974   2105
9            Belgium  Female  OUT  1974   2100
10           Belgium   Total  IN  1974   4517
```

***As a start*** in my code I am using the following libraries (in Jupyter notebook with offline plot maps):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly as py
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from IPython import display
import os
py.offline.init_notebook_mode()
```

***Then***, in order to avoid any errors, I am replacing the '-' values with 0 and I am also grouping by the needed column (Year):

```
#Replace non numerical values from the Value column
df1['Value'] = df1['Value'].replace('-', np.nan)

#Groupby Country
df1 = df1.groupby(['Year'], as_index=False)['Value'].sum()
```

***Then***, I use a plot to create a graph:

```
#Plot everything in a graph
py.offline.iplot({
    "data": [go.Line(x=df1.Year,
            y=df1.Value)],
    "layout": go.Layout(title="Immigration through the years")
})
```

My question is... Can I alter the last bit where I create the graph, in order to filter/replace values or `groupby`? Then, I can get rid of the 2 steps before creating the graph.

Comment: Hi, could you add an example of your desired output?

Comment: @Interested_Programmer Please do not randomly reply just to boost you reputation. The output would be the same in any case above. I am asking a different thing.

Comment: I was asking for an example as I had to manually reproduce your df and wanted to see the plot before I reproduce them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach already seems to be the right and cleaner way!

The two lines involving `replace` and `groupBy` is a data preparation step. The last step is the visualization(or data presentation) step. Keeping them separate makes your code more readable!

Also, the two lines involving `replace` and `groupBy` cannot be merged as it involves modifying a row and aggregating on some other row.

Comment: Good to know. Next step is to simplify the dataframe to have the Year and the Value and predict the Value for the n+1 and n+2 years. If you have any documentations, you are welcome to post them here.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are looking for forecasting algorithms: https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecast-study-python-monthly-sales-french-champagne/

Comment: Yes. I am trying to implement the easiest solution for N+2 years. It is gonna take a while :P